# How to upload image from absolute url into storage?

Tags: laravel

I need to upload image from absolute url, into storage, like

```
Storage::disk('local')->put($destImagePath, File::get($imageFileAbsoluteUrl));
```

I got error :

```
  File does not exist at path ...
```

as I need to pass File::get(  path of file (not url)
I do not use Spatie Media Library in this project

Which is valid way ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^9.30",
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should log or dump the value of `$imageFileAbsoluteUrl`, then `File::get($imageFileAbsoluteUrl)`. Make sure they're what you expect.

Comment: I have checked that $imageFileAbsoluteUrl has absolute url

Comment: And have you checked that `File::get` works on that URL?

Comment: Yes, I got error :

  File does not exist at path ..

Comment: Then your absolute URL is incorrect, or you don't have permission to access it. What's the value of `$imageFileAbsoluteUrl`?